# Periodic network scan

Tags: ios, swift

I need to retrieve values from a TCP server every 0.5 seconds to display on an iPhone. I would like to start/stop the scan from a segmented switch. The IBAction function from the Start segment does not seem to remain in that function. Adding a while statement doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a snippet of one failing attempt. This code merely prints 0,1,2,3,4 then goes away. If I break at self.getValues() after what should be the delay (doesn't work either), it never gets there.:

```
@IBAction func switchChange(_ sender: Any) {
    switch statrStopSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
        case 0:         //Start scanning
            if wifiStatus {
                getValues()
                var pass = 0;
                while statrStopSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
                    print (pass)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30.0, execute: {
                        self.getValues()
                    })
                    pass += 1
                }
            }
            else{               // Wifi not connected
                notConnectedMessage()  // Issue alert message
            }
        case 1:         //Stop scanning
            ScanStatusLabel.text = "SCAN HALTED"
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use busy loops on the main queue (or really on any queue). At that point your app is dead and will not do anything except show lots of print statements. Use a Timer.

Comment: rmaddy, I'm a novice with Swift. Can you show me a timer example? Thanks.